# Change Fedora 12 Hostname through gui

Tags: networking, fedora

How can I change fedora 12 hostname using gui tools (network connections) only, without editing config files?

All I can see right now if I select "Manual" in IPv4 settings is "DNS servers" or DHCP client ID, neither of which sounds like "domain/hostname" combination.

Tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be under System->Administration->Network

Here is a [link](http://www.labtestproject.com/using_linux/permanently_change_hostname_on_fedora) with step-by-step instructions.